# Mysql crosstab fixed column query does not display certain multi language characters

Tags: mysql

I am looking for help in understanding the issue with retrieving certain characters in MYSQL. I have a table which contains international numerals in unicode for each numeral system (e.g. Roman, Hebrew, Thai, Khmer, Lao, etc). The character set of the table is utf8 and collation is utf8_general_ci.

The table is organised as follows:

| NUM_SYS_NAME | NUM_ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Roman | 1 | I |
| Roman | 2 | II |
| Roman | 3 | III |
| Roman | 5 | V |
| Thai | 5 | ๕ |
| Ethiopic | 500 | ፭፻ |

etc, there are 18 numbers for each numeral system, from 0 to 10, also 50, 100, 500, 1000, 10000.

The MySql query is this:

```
SELECT NUM_SYS_NAME,
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 0 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '0',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 1 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '1',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 2 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '2',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 3 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '3',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 4 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '4',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 5 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '5',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 6 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '6',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 7 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '7',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 8 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '8',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 9 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '9',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 10 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '10',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 50 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '50',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 100 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '100',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 500 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '500',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 1000 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '1000',
       max(case
             when NUM_ID = 10000 then
              TEXT
             else
              'N/A'
           end) as '10000'
  from numerals
 WHERE NUM_ID IN
       (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 10000)
 GROUP BY NUM_SYS_NAME
```

The results are properly retrieved and formatted in a crosstab as expected, except for Roman numerals from 1 to 4 and also 9, 50, 100, 1000, 10000. So, for example, Roman numeral 5 will be displayed as V and 3 as N/A. If I set the value of the Roman numeral 3 to ZZZ instead of III is it then displayed properly in query results.

I have experimented with various collations and also setting the values in TEXT field to other characters for Roman numeral system and have found that any character from O to Z is displayed properly, however, anything else results in an N/A value, hence all numerals starting with I, L, D, C in Roman system are not retrieved. I am cracking my head now for 2 days to find the root cause of the issue and believe this has to do something a collation and mixing multiple languages, but not very sure, moreover, it is bizarre that the issue is with basic latin characters rather than the exotic ones.

Would appreciate your advice and to be pointed to the right direction. So far, could not even find a similar issue via search or help docs.

Thanks in advance!
Alex

P.S. Table definition:
[numerals Table definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfX1O.png)

P.S. 2
Fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/op6eAg6s6mDWJiFRYXyYFS/3

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through  It may help you figure out what's wrong. If not, please [edit] your question to show us your table definition and [connection character set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) ?

Comment: Fiddle provided in post edit. Here it is as well: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/op6eAg6s6mDWJiFRYXyYFS/3

Comment: @O. Jones > Connection parameters: mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"). I think there may be the issue, since connection is established under "unicode_ci" whereas DB table collation is "general_ci". Can this be the problem?

Comment: @O. Jones - thanks also for the links to the discussion on UTF8, it was very useful for other reasons, learned a lot there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding isn't the issue, it's about using `MAX()`

`max(case when NUM_ID = 4 then TEXT else 'N/A' end) as '4',`  <-- the string `'N/A'` is *greater* than the string `'IV'`, in alphabetic order, and then, the `'N/A'` is selected over the `'IV'`, or anything that has sorting order lesser than `'N/A'`. That's why the letter `'O'` works, because it's after `'N'`.

A workaround would be to replace the string `'N/A'` by the value `NULL` :

```
MAX(case when NUM_ID = 4 then TEXT else NULL end) as '4'
```

Comment: So elegant and simple in the end, thanks for saving the headache. Works beautifully now! Much appreciated!

Comment: @AlexBein well, this problem puzzled me and I **had** to dig a little :p